# Where can I download Sharepoint DLLs

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I need to get hold of the Sharepoint DLL's.  I understand that these are available from the Sharepoint server however the company I work for is quite large and the server is not anywhere I can get close to to copy the DLL's.  Is there somewhere I can download these so I can start to develop my VB.NET application locally!

Answer (score 4):

You need to be developing on a Virtual Machine with SharePoint installed on that machine. If your company has an MSDN subscription you should have the ability to download installation media, if it is not already available.

However Microsoft has guidance on doing this on your physical machine [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx).

Comment: I cannot vote this up enough - run a virtual machine! You will will save hours (days?) of headache, confusion and frustration.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Sharepoint Foundation installer from here:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en

No MSDN is required - this is a free download, and Sharepoint Foundation is completely free, as long as you already have SQL Server and Windows Server already licensed.

As Nat has mentioned, it is highly recommended to do development on a virtual machine, and to have the full Sharepoint setup installed there.

Here is a setup guide, but there are many others out there:
http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/DennisBottjer/archive/2009/11/30/sharepoint-2010-foundation-development-demonstration-installation-guide.aspx

After you have Sharepoint installed on your VM, you can find the DLLs under c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows SharePoint Services to get it.
You can download it from below URL 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14117

is located in Local_Drive:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts